# Jenkins: what are the risks of upgrading Java 6 to Java 8?

Tags: java, jenkins, glassfish, upgrade, compatibility

At work, I have inherited two instances of Jenkins. One runs legacy jobs on Java 1.5. The other runs newer projects on Java 1.6.

I have been asked to upgrade both instances to Java 1.8.

This will involve upgrading:

- **Java** 1.6 to 1.8
- **Jenkins** from 1.460 to 1.614
- **Glassfish** from 3.1.2 to 4.1

**Question:**

What should I be aware of as I start to upgrade? (E.g. risks of upgrading from JDK6 to JDK8)

Are there any known compatibility errors between these versions?

Comment: Please don't downvote without suggesting improvements. I don't do revenge downvoting - you're safe.

Answer (score 9):

You are upgrading three things at once ... not just the version of Java ... so it will be difficult to identify the risks reliably.  (The risks are probably not that great, but if you are into risk mitigation, that is too vague for you.)

However, I don't really think that "identifying the risks" is what you should focus on.  What you should be doing is formulating an upgrade strategy that makes the risks irrelevant.  Basically, you need a guaranteed rollback strategy in case the upgrade goes badly.

I would do something like this:

- Get a new server machine, or a new virtual machine.
- Install the new versions of Java and Glassfish on the new server.
- Clone the existing Jenkins instance by:

  - Backup the state of the existing Jenkins instance (see [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins))
  - Install same version of Jenkins as the existing instance on the new server.
  - Restore the backup onto the new server.
- Check that the new server is functioning (still old version).
- Use Jenkins' automatic upgrade facility to upgrade the new server to the target version.
- Install Jenkins plugins, etc.
- Test new server.
- Put new server into production.

The key thing here is that you are doing the upgrade on a new system. If something goes wrong with the upgrade, your existing system is still in full working order.  If necessary, you can repeat the procedure multiple times until you get it right, or you can spend days or weeks tweaking the new CI system while the rest of your team continue using the current production CI system.

And while you are at it, you could take this opportunity to refresh the base operating system

Comment: Getting a new VM is a way to start. But can you help me with the strategy to  build java 6 web application on java 8?

Comment: Nope.  You could a new question, but note that this one was closed as "too broad" ... and yours probably would too.